# Are block scope variables are immediately removed from memory?

Tags: variables, scope

If we are defining variables inside if else block or while block, are this variables immediately going to deleted after block ends? what happens behind the scene?

```
int foo()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       int x=i;
       System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

when x variable will be deleted from memory?

Comment: This is highly language dependent. Based on your code sample are you referring to Java?

Comment: yes i am referring to java